# How do I store a stream of characters in an array?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a stream of characters coming over the serial port like this;

```
FILE1,FILE2,FILE3,
```

I'm trying to read them in like this;

```
char* myFiles[20];
boolean done = false;
int fileNum = 0;
int charPos = 0;
char character;
while (!done)
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    character = Serial.read();
    if ((character == '\n') || (character == '\r'))
    {
      done = true;
    }
    else if (character == ',')
    {
      myFiles[fileNum][charPos] = '\0';
      fileNum++;
      charPos = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      myFiles[fileNum][charPos] = character;
      charPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to print the first value like this;

```
Serial.println(myFiles[0]);
```

i get a continuous stream of characters.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing wrong is not allocating any memory for your strings.

Here's one way to do this

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> myFiles;
std::string file;
bool done = false;
char character;
while (!done)
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    character = Serial.read();
    if ((character == '\n') || (character == '\r'))
    {
      done = true;
    }
    else if (character == ',')
    {
      myfiles.push_back(file);
      file = "";
    }
    else
    {
      file += character;
    }
  }
}

Serial.println(myFiles[0].c_str());
```

Since you are programming in C++ you should learn how to use `std::vector` and `std::string`, they will save you a lot of grief.

If `std::vector` and `std::string` are not available to you (apparently so on Arduino) then the quick hack would be to preallocate a fixed amount of memory for your strings by replacing

```
char* myFiles[20];
```

with

```
char myFiles[20][100];
```

Comment: std::vector and std::string are not available on the Arduino.

Comment: Hmm that's unfortunate. The quick hack then would be to replace `char* myFiles[20];` with `char myFiles[20][100];` in the original code. A better solution would be C like code with malloc, realloc etc.

Comment: changing to char myFiles[20][100]; works, so if you add that as an answer, then I can accept it.